# How do I update the photoUrl ? photoUrl : null

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I want to update photoUrl but from my code I can upload images to storage but in my document photoUrl : Null

**updatePhoto.dart**

```
void _savePhotoToFirebase() async {
    String userID = Utils.getRandomString(8) + Random().nextInt(500).toString();
    String postPhotoUrl;
    FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    var userUpdateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
    userUpdateInfo.photoUrl = postPhotoUrl;
    if (_postPhotoFile != null) {
      postPhotoUrl = await CSStorage.uploadPhotoUrl(
          userID: userID, postPhotoFile: _postPhotoFile);
    }
    FBCloudStore.sendPhotoToFirebase(
        userID, postPhotoUrl ?? 'NONE', currentUser);
  }
```

**CSStorage.dart**

```
    static Future<String> uploadPhotoUrl({
        @required String userID,
        @required File postPhotoFile,
        }) async {
        try {
          String fileName = 'users/$userID/photoUrl';
          StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
          StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(postPhotoFile);
          StorageTaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
          String postPhotoUrl = await storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
          return postPhotoUrl;
        }catch(e) {
          return null;
        }
      }
```

**FBCloudStore.dart**

```
static Future<void> sendPhotoToFirebase(
      String userID, String postPhotoUrl, FirebaseUser firebaseUser) async {
    Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(userID).setData({
      'userID': userID,
      'displayName': firebaseUser.displayName,
      'photoUrl': firebaseUser.photoUrl,
    });
  }
```

Comment: Where in the code you shared are you adding the photo URL to the document?

Comment: I have updated the question(cloudStore.dart). That's what you're asking me, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `sendPhotoToFirebase` function, you're writing `firebaseUser.photoUrl` to the database. But that is **not** the URL of the photo you just uploaded. To write the latter:

```
static Future<void> sendPhotoToFirebase(
    String userID, String postPhotoUrl, FirebaseUser firebaseUser) async {
  Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(userID).setData({
    'userID': userID,
    'displayName': firebaseUser.displayName,
    'photoUrl': postPhotoUrl, //  Change here
  });
}
```